# Initializing a 2D array with user-defined size

Tags: java, arrays

This is for a battleship program and the height/width of the array is passed in through a different method (called promptInt). I'm not sure how to go about calling a method to determine the size of the array. \

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

1. As atributes to the method use field height and width, then create the array of arrays
2. Use `Vector` or `List` like `List<List<type>> chart = new ArrayList<>();`
   and then append new vector: `chart.add(Collections.singleton(Config.WATER_CHAR));`
   then to get data: `chart.get(row).get(column)` and setting: `chart.get(row).set(column, boat/miss)`
3. Do not use 2D array, use linear array or arraylist and then calculate the position. This is the simplest solution, you will avoid the unnecessary operations with 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = 10;

// Initialize the array
char[][] board = new char[size][size];
initBoard(board);

// File the array with values
public static void initBoard(char[][] board) {
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            board[x][y] = Config.WATER_CHAR;
}
```

You first need to initialize the array which you **have** to do outside of the initBoard() method. Then inside initBoard() you can fill the array with values.

Comment: Ok I understand this, but for my program, there isn't a set size (like 10) I need to get it from a different method called promptInt  which has the parameter int num... I'm just confused on what to set int size equal to

Comment: The most easy way to do that is using a scanner for command line input or a joptionpane to show a pop-up dialog.

Comment: I can't somehow call the method to get the values?